# retrieve values from url - post in form

Tags: php, javascript, html, url

I want to retrieve some values from my url and post them in a form.

For example:

url =   hello.com/hello.php?id=**3**

My Form:

Id = **3**

What code do I need to access the value for id? Some kind of post? Or get? Or script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any values appended to the end of a URL will be available in a PHP script via the [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) global variable.  So in your case you can retrieve the ID in php by doing: `$_GET['id']`

Variables submitted via a form whose method = 'post' are available through the $_POST variable.

If you want to put that data in a form field do:

```
<input type="text" name="something" value="<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>" />
```

although your probably don't want to just stick $_GET['id'] in as a value without checking / sanitizing it first.
http://www.cgisecurity.com/xss-faq.html

Answer (score 1):

Refer to your variable as `$_GET['id']`. An example of using it in a HTML form would be something like:

```
<input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>">
```

Use this as an example only ;)

Comment: It also doubles as an example of an XSS hole :P

Comment: Obviously. I never said 'copy and paste this into your live code' :) I've editted the response.

Comment: @alex, instead of commenting with the typical XSS argument , why dont you help and tell us how to prevent it?

Comment: @tada You could cast it `(int) $_GET['id']`, which will only preserve the integer portion up until the first non integer.

Answer (score 0):

$localvar=$_GET['id'];

If you had posted the data using method="post" in your  html you would refer to it as:

$localvar=$_POST['id'];